# Axis break with gap.plot while data contains NAs

Tags: r, axis, break

I want to make a x-axis break with `gap.plot()` function from package **`plotrix`** while my data contains `NAs`.
My code works fine if there aren´t any `NAs` but with `NAs` it tells me:

> Error in if (lostones) warning("some values of x will not be
>   displayed") :    argument is not interpretable as logical

and it doesn´t plot anything at all.

dt is just an example dataset

```
dt <- data.frame(c(1.2,NA,5,6,4.3,1),c(22,33,22,25,NA,27))
names(dt) <- c("a","b")

library(plotrix)
gap.plot(dt$a, dt$b, gap=c(1.5,3.5), gap.axis="x",col="blue", ylim=range(c(dt$b)),xtics=c(0:1.5,3.5:6), xticlab=c(0:1.5,3.5:6))

abline(v=1.5, col="white")
abline(v=1.56, col="white", lwd=4)  

axis.break(1,breakpos=1.55,style="slash", brw=0.03)   
axis.break(3,breakpos=1.55,style="slash", brw=0.03)
```

What do I have to change? By the way I don´t want to use `ggplot`.

Comment: Omitting `NAs` with `na.omit(dt)` is not an acceptable solution?

Comment: Thank´s a lot. It works finally.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to produce a scatterplot, you have to omit your lines that contain `NA`.

For example:

```
dt <- data.frame(c(1.2,NA,5,6,4.3,1),c(22,33,22,25,NA,27)) 
names(dt) <- c("a","b")
```

Now remove your NA's:

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- dt %>%
  na.omit()
```

Plot:

```
library(plotrix)

gap.plot(dt$a, dt$b, gap=c(1.5,3.5), gap.axis="x",col="blue", ylim=range(dt$b) ,xtics=c(0:1.5,3.5:6), xticlab=c(0:1.5,3.5:6))

abline(v=1.5, col="white")
abline(v=1.56, col="white", lwd=4)

axis.break(1,breakpos=1.55,style="slash", brw=0.03)
axis.break(3,breakpos=1.55,style="slash", brw=0.03)
```

Result:

[image]